# Is it possible to animate height change in MUI Dialog?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customizeddialogs-demo-material-ui-forked-m7h4n2?file=/demo.tsx) that shows the problem.

We load an MUI dialog with a content. Then we load more content dynamically (it's simulated there using a `setTimeout`) and change the content of the dialog.

This results in an abrupt height change.

I read the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/) and I can't find a setting for this.

How can I tell MUI to smoothly change its height on content change?

Comment: Does the height always change by the same value? Do you know exactly how big the change is?

Comment: @sm3sher, no, the content's height is not known.

Comment: In case of a fixed height change I would recommend using `<Skeleton />` from material ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the height change less interrupting by wrapping it inside a `<Collapse />` which also comes with material ui.

```
          <Collapse in={!progress}>
            <>
              <Typography gutterBottom>
                Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur
                et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus
                dolor auctor.
              </Typography>
              <Typography gutterBottom>
                Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo
                cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed
                odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
              </Typography>
            </>
          </Collapse>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit CustomizedDialogs demo — Material UI (forked)]

Comment: Perfect. Sometimes we literally can't see the tools there. Functional fixedness.

Comment: You're welcome ;) that's why we're here